# Show/hide marker based on external event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a marker within a function, but need to show/hide it based on an event elsewhere on the page, unconnected to the map. I have tried using "marker1.setVisible(true);" within the event, but I get the error "marker1 is not defined". Is there another way I can reference it or can I somehow make the marker globally available?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Andrew.

Comment: "I have created a marker within a function"..."marker1 is not defined" - Provide the code where you create the marker. If code part of the code thinks it is undefined, we should start there, but we need to see the full code to determine this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare marker1 as global variable.
 "A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL.
 A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page    can access it."

something like:

```
var marker1;

function setMarker(){
    //....
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,.....})
   //....
}
```

will let you use "marker1.setVisible(true);" somewhere else in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have declared marker1 outside any function, but when I use "marker1.setVisible(true)" from within a function I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVisible' of undefined".

Comment: Check if you have somewhere else inside a function have used "var marker1 = ...." instead of "marker1 = .... "

Comment: Thanks, that's embarrassingly simple.